# Improving recursive SQL looping

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to solve a performance issue on an inherited system that appears when we have a significant amount of data.

We have a table that contains the two fields "ItemID" and "ParentItemID".
The "ParentItemID" field relates to another row in the same talbe where the "ItemID" field matches this row's "ParentItemID" field.

This relationship can be many, many rows deep in places.

The following query is being run and looks like it could be another cause of slowdown:

```
WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
    SELECT @ParentID = ParentItemID FROM Items WHERE ItemID = @LastParentID
    IF @parentID IS NULL
    BEGIN
        break
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @LastParentID = @ParentID
    END
END
```

Is there a better way of doing this sort of recursive search?

note: we are NOT allowed to make table changes at this point, so adding a "RootItemID" column is not possible (I've already asked, as this would solve the problem outright!)

Comment: No table changes allowed at all? I mean are you also not allowed to create new tables? Because you could also solve this by calculating that rootparentid on insert by using a trigger and saving that in a seperate table that you could then just join on.

Comment: I suppose we COULD do it that way.. would that be quicker than using the CTE approach detailed below?

Comment: Well, it pushes the calculation to the time of insertion so it would be done only once and not when simply selecting. Also this is not only an alternative but an addition, you COULD use CTE approach in a trigger to get that root parent item and insert it then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a common table expression for this:

```
WITH Antecedents (ITemID, ParentItemID, Level)
AS
(
    -- Anchor member definition
    SELECT ItemID, ParentItemID, 0 AS Level FROM Items WHERE ItemID = @StartingID

    UNION ALL

    SELECT ItemID, ParentItemID, Antecedents.Level + 1 AS Level 
    FROM Items 
    INNER JOIN Antecedents
      ON Antecedents.ParentItemID = Items.ItemID

)

SELECT TOP 1 @LastParentID = ItemID 
FROM Antecedents
ORDER BY Level DESC
```

More info on recursive CTE's here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by a `Common Table Expression` like :

```
;WITH cte_hierarchy
     AS (SELECT *
         FROM   item
         WHERE  ItemID = @ParentID
         UNION ALL
         SELECT i.*
         FROM   item i
                JOIN cte_hierarchy h
                  ON i.ItemID = h.ParentItemID)
SELECT *
FROM   cte_hierarchy 
WHERE  .....
```

Comment: I accepted Paddy's answer over yours only because he included the more info link. Your answer is also right, and have upvoted accordingly. thanks!